# Aqueduct - right or duty?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

Rules:

> If, when the dice are rolled for production, you do not receive any resources or commodities, you may take any one resource of your choice from the bank. You may not, however, use this ability when a "7" is rolled.

But is this right or duty? May I not use this ability and not take a resource? For example, I have seven cards in my hand and I don't want to have more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 'May' is optional

It is pretty much universal among board games that if the game says you 'may' take an action, that action is optional. If the word 'may' is not present, the action is usually mandatory.

> If, when the dice are rolled for production, you do not receive any resources or commodities, you **MAY** take any one resource of your choice from the bank. You may not, however, use this ability when a "7" is rolled.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: That's what "may" means in the [common English sense too](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/may#Etymology_1). In some [other contexts, it's also codified](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) that it means something actually optional. Board games usually don't go as far as defining words like that, but yeah, luckily they do use the word in the same sense.